# Statistics: Binomials

Tags: statistics, expected-value

Suppose that 30% of all students who have to buy a textbook for a particular course want a new copy, whereas the other 70% want a used copy. Consider a random sample of 25 students.

(b) Suppose that new copies cost \$100 and used copies cost \$70. Assume the bookstore currently has 50 new copies and 50 used copies. What is the expected value of total revenue from the sale of the next 25 copies purchased?

I know that for expected value 
$E(X)=\sum_x h(x)*p(x),$ and for problems with constants, it would be a $E(x)+b.$ I just don't know how to apply that here.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The \$ character has a special meaning in [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference); to get a regular \$ character, type \\\$

Comment: Please take the tour and add a `self-study` tag. // I have edited your question; please check to see that I did not change your meaning. What is $h(x)?$ Do you want $E(X) = \sum_x xp(x),$ where the sum is taken over all values $x$ in the support of $X?$ Or do you want $E[h(X)] = \sum_x h(x)p(x)?$ // Maybe $E(aX+b) = aE(X)+b$ is more relevant. // Maybe almost \$2000.

Comment: Thanks. I mean E(aX+b)=aE(X)+b